# My Pixel 2 doesn't give me a notification when I attach it to a PC

Tags: file-transfer, usb-connection-mode, google-pixel-2

I've had a new Pixel 2 XL for a few days now. Today when I plug it in to a PC the PC detects that it is present but doesn't show the list of files present on the device.

When I did this a few days ago, I had a similar experience, but a notification popped up on the phone asking me what mode I wanted to use. It was set to "recharge" by default, but when I changed it to "file sharing" (exact wording might not be right) the files appeared in the browser on my PC.

Today there is no notification. I have tried unplugging the device and plugging it back in several times. Did I do something to disable the notification? **How can I re-enable the notification or better yet set it so that it *always* turns on file share mode when I plug it in?**

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a lock-screen enabled on it? Most Android phones will require you to unlock it before it will connect to the file system. If you don't have a lock-screen, you may want to check out [this article](https://www.addictivetips.com/android/how-to-set-the-default-usb-connection-type-in-android-6-0/) and make sure it's set to file mode, and mot just MTP or charging.

Comment: I believe the feature is buggy. You nudged me in the right direction. From the article you linked, the "Select USB Configuration" dialog is the one I need. However, it is set to MTP but fails to operate unless I tap the MTP option again, then it works. I even unplugged and reverified that. The setting says MTP, I plug it in, the Pixel 2 XL shows up in the browser but no files, I tap the MTP option again (even though it is already selected) and then the files appear in the PC. I hope they fix that!

Comment: The comments under the linked article (which is for Android 6) indicate that the MTP setting doesn't stick for many users. I am on Android 8 and it still isn't fixed. I guess we can forget it about it ever being fixed.